# Aligning images next to eachother within a div

Tags: image, html, alignment

I have two images contained in one div and am trying to align the second image next to the first. If I assign each image a class, how can I get the second image to be aligned with the first using css? Or is it best to have a div for each image?

`<div class="standard">
    <img src="images/room02.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/room04.jpg"/>
</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate div or class for each image. It all depends on how you want to align them. Just see this guide for more information: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/insert-images-website/align-float-images-css

Comment: I want the second image to be aligned horizontally with the first one. I have tried .standard img{float: right;} and that hasn't done anything.

Comment: If the images are drastically different, you might have to use negative padding on a specific image. It would help if you made a JSFiddle link with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is the link to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/james26591/HEqSf/. I'm trying to horizontally align the two images under standard rooms. I'm sure there is an easy fix, but I am a beginner and still  learning the ropes. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: @user3571327, there you go: http://jsfiddle.net/HEqSf/1/. You were basically trying to make each image take up 100% of the `div`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I thought there would be a simple fix. Cheers

Comment: @user3571327, you're welcome. If this resolved your issue, please accept my answer so those who search the site with a similar issue can see right away that it was solved and follow our thread.